# WP-admin or any other is redirecting me to (This page doesn't seem to exist.)

Tags: wp-admin, login

I am logging in to my website with URL/wp-admin or other methods but it is redirecting me to ( This page doesn't seem to exist. ) here.

Please guide me on how to do I log in to my website.

See the Screenshot to see the issue.
[image]

Comment: check to make sure your wp-login.php file is still on your site/server. And if it is, temporarily rename your `.htaccess` in the root of your website to see if that works.

Comment: Yes, it is available in file manager.

Comment: @PaulG. Thanks, I have renamed the .htacess file and it is working now, But what to do with the .htacess file now?

Comment: Make a copy of it somewhere safe, just in case you find something else isn't working, and delete it. Then go to WP Settings > Permalinks > Save.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will.

Comment: @PaulG. can you post your answer as an answer?

Comment: @TheGamePlay - I've posted my comment as the answer - would you be able to click to accept it please?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was 1 of 2 things:

Either the `wp-login.php` file wasn't present, or the permalinks structure was corrupt or incorrectly setup in the `.htaccess`.  The solution then is 1 of the following:

1. Ensure the file `wp-login.php` file is present on the site. If not, download the WordPress zip from wordpress.org for your WP version and place it there.
2. temporarily rename the `.htaccess` file to remove its effect. If this works, log into your WordPress site, goto Settings > Permalinks and then Save.

In this case it was `.htaccess` which needed rebuilt.